# Pagination using Doctrine and ZF2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

i am trying to implement Pagination Using ZF2 and Doctrine.

What i am trying to do here is to fetch data from An associated table lets say 'xyz'.

Where as my categories table is doing one to many self referencing on its own PK.
  MY catgories tables has following feilds

- ID (PK)
- Created_at
- Category_id (self referencing PK)

My XYZ table lets say it is called Name table has

- ID (PK)
- Category_id(FK)
- name
- Detail

This is what i am trying to  do to fetch data

```
      public function allSubcategories($id, $column, $order) {
 $repository = $this->entityManager->getRepository('Category\Entity\Category');
    $queryBuilder = $repository->createQueryBuilder('category');
    $queryBuilder->distinct();
    $queryBuilder->select('category');

    $queryBuilder->join('Category\Entity\CategoryName', 'category_name', 'WITH', 'category.id = category_name.category');
    $queryBuilder->orderBy("category.status");
    $q = $queryBuilder->getDql();
    return $query = $this->entityManager->createQuery($q);
}
```

And in my controller this is what i am doing

```
      public function subcategoryAction() {

    ///////////////////////////InPut Params Given for the pagination
    $category_id = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('id', 0);
    $page = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('page', 0);
    $column = $this->params()->fromQuery('column');
    $order = $this->params()->fromQuery('order');



    $categoryModel = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Category');
    $categoryModel->category = $category_id;


    $perPage = 10;
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isGet()) {
        $view = new ViewModel();
        $query = $categoryModel->allSubcategories($category_id, $column, $order);

        $paginator = new ORMPaginator($query);

        $paginator = new \Zend\Paginator\Paginator(new
                        \Zend\Paginator\Adapter\ArrayAdapter(array($paginator)));
        $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page);
        $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(2);

    }

    return array('id' => $category_id, 'view' => $paginator);
}
```

Now i am not getting results with pagination implemented can some 1 guide me about what i am missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using the wrong paginator there. Instead, you can use the one by [`DoctrineORMModule`](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule) ( see [`DoctrineORMModule\Paginator\Adapter\DoctrinePaginator`](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule/blob/0.7.0/src/DoctrineORMModule/Paginator/Adapter/DoctrinePaginator.php)).

It may not be very obvious, but the logic is similar to what you already wrote:

```php
use DoctrineORMModule\Paginator\Adapter\DoctrinePaginator as PaginatorAdapter;
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator as ORMPaginator;
use Zend\Paginator\Paginator as ZendPaginator;

$query = $categoryModel->allSubcategories($category_id, $column, $order);

$paginator = new ZendPaginator(new PaginatorAdapter(new ORMPaginator($query)));
```

Comment: i just modified it to 
 $adapter = new DoctrineAdapter(new ORMPaginator($categoryModel->allSubcategories($category_id, $column, $order), true));
            $paginator = new Paginator($adapter);

Comment: and  public function allSubcategories($id, $column, $order) {
        $repository = $this->entityManager->getRepository('Category\Entity\Category');
        $queryBuilder = $repository->createQueryBuilder('category');
        $queryBuilder->select('category');
        $queryBuilder->join('Category\Entity\CategoryName', 'category_name', 'WITH', 'category.id = category_name.category');
        $queryBuilder->orderBy("category.status");
        $q = $queryBuilder->getDql();
        $query = $this->entityManager->createQuery($q);
        $results = $query->getResult();
        return $results;
 }

Comment: Now i am getting this error  Argument 1 passed to Doctrine\\ORM\\Tools\\Pagination\\Paginator::cloneQuery() must be an instance of Doctrine\\ORM\\Query, array given  
how to overcome this

Comment: @noobie-php pass the query to the `ORMPaginator`, not the query's result.

Comment: i passed it the Query.Now i am getting another error check if you can sort it out


    Error producing an iterator

Stack trace:

    #0 /var/www/myproject/module/Admin/view/admin/category/subcategory.phtml(17): Zend\Paginator\Paginator->getIterator()

Along with this 



    /var/www/whowantsmymoney/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/Pagination/WhereInWalker.php:82

Message:

    Cannot count query which selects two FROM components, cannot make distinction

Comment: @noobie-php is the query the same you pasted in your example? Because it should work now. Try selecting only the category in the `SELECT` clause

Comment: Posting it again, Please have a look its same with only addition of Distinct Clause

 $repository = $this->entityManager->getRepository('Category\Entity\Category');
        $queryBuilder = $repository->createQueryBuilder('category');
        $queryBuilder->distinct();
        $queryBuilder->select('category');

        $queryBuilder->join('Category\Entity\CategoryName', 'category_name', 'WITH', 'category.id = category_name.category');
        $queryBuilder->orderBy("category.status");
        $q = $queryBuilder->getDql();
        return $query = $this->entityManager->createQuery($q);

Comment: Can you please pastebin instead of using comments?

Comment: @noobie-php the query you pasted is not supported by the paginator. You will have to `$query->getResults()` and then use an array adapter for pagination.