# How to create pagination using ZF2 and Doctrine?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, pagination, zend-framework2

I am trying to add pagination to my simple site. I am using Zf2 and Doctrine2 orm.

Doctrine2 intruduced their own paginator in 2.2 version. You can find example [here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/pagination.html). Code of this example:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator;

$dql = "SELECT p, c FROM BlogPost p JOIN p.comments c";
$query = $entityManager->createQuery($dql)
                       ->setFirstResult(0)
                       ->setMaxResults(100);

$paginator = new Paginator($query, $fetchJoinCollection = true);

$c = count($paginator);
foreach ($paginator as $post) {
    echo $post->getHeadline() . "\n";
}
```

There are only one example at linked page. In this example shown how to create paginator with DQL. I am not using DQL and I am getting data using object manager (there are N parts of code with such code).

I am using a bit another approach to work with db. I am using something like this:

```
// $this->objectManager is being set in __construct

$news = $this->objectManager                     
    ->getRepository('\News\Entity\Item')         
    ->findBy($options, array('created'=>'DESC'));

$items = array();                           
foreach ($news as $item) {                  
    $items[] = $item->getArrayCopy();       
}                                           
return $items;
```

Is there any way to make pagination without using DQL, like in example? Is it possible to add pagination to my approach?

Comment: See the answer here -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/15069279/1112089

Comment: I saw this post. I saw author is using query builder so I didn't even read other post. My bad. I will do it now.

Comment: Hm. I am getting error. Can you clarify what I did wrong? [This](https://github.com/sharikovvladislav/my-zf2-project/blob/testing/module/News/config/module.config.php#L26-L35) is route `news`. [This](https://github.com/sharikovvladislav/my-zf2-project/blob/testing/module/News/src/News/Controller/NewsController.php#L50-L71) is path of the controller where I am trying to add pagination. I am getting [this](http://i.gyazo.com/488645a202331976d18137c2d3837b08.png) error (`.png` 14.75 kb)

Comment: @Crisp or should I create new question?

Comment: The paginator expects a query object, the findby method returns an array hence the error. It's beyond the scope of a single answer as it stands, start with the docs and learn how to build a query that you *can* pass to the paginator -> http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/query-builder.html

Comment: @Crisp thanks for your answer. It is not problem to use query build like so. Is it better or worse way to work with DB? I thought more acceptable way is to use `om`, isn't it? Okay. I have [this code](https://github.com/sharikovvladislav/my-zf2-project/blob/46a6110e958c74d19f2e126d9078a782e5fedb80/module/News/src/News/Controller/NewsController.php#L51-L79) at the moment. I am getting [this](http://i.gyazo.com/608b2f14fb0b129fabcff74717480ff9.png) by `var_dump()` + 3 news items on the page. But it must be 5 items per page. Why I am geting only 3?

Comment: Well... Should I use old approach? Or it is better to use as I have now at my code?

Comment: I understand what caused problem, also I found newer docs. 1 moment :) What approach to work with data is better? Current one (with query builder) or working with object manager?

Comment: Also, "code review" question. I have to check if wrong page called right? Like if user will try to access 999 page. I have to put some conditions. Should I do it in `getItems` or there are some better approach?

Comment: @Crisp well, does [this](https://github.com/sharikovvladislav/my-zf2-project/blob/dfb0243dafcc3ad08411d936fcbec79f707d7abb/module/News/src/News/Controller/NewsController.php#L51-L76) code look good?

Comment: Yes, your latest code seems fine.

Comment: @Crisp if you want, you may write answer, in which you will summarize all, what you said in comments and I will accept it. You had helped me so many times yet. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

something like this .

```
 class Doctor extends EntityRepository
       { 
        public function getPagedDoctor($offset = 0, $limit = 10)
            {
                $em = $this->getEntityManager();
                $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();

                $qb->select('d')
                    ->from('\Application\Entity\Doctor', 'd')
                    ->orderBy('d.fullName')
                    ->setMaxResults($limit)
                    ->setFirstResult($offset);

                $query = $qb->getQuery();
                $paginator = new Paginator( $query );

                return $paginator;
            }
}
```